# php - to pass mysql information from php to the next page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have linked mysql in php and printed it as a table.
Then click on the name to go to the web page.
What I want to do is to pop up different web page information every time I click on it.
For example, if you want to pass to main.php -> sub.php,
'main.php' "apple" click -> 'sub.php' print "apple!!!!"

**script code**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("table tr td").click(function(){
          displayComment(num);
        });
    });
    function displayComment(num) {
      var txt = $(this).text();
    location.href = "http://220.67.127.177/0513_sub";
}
  </script>
```

**php code**

```
 <?php

   $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_passwd,$db_name);    
   mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");            
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Market");
   echo "<table border=’1′> <tr> <th>시장 이름</th> </tr>";
   $n = 1;    
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
     echo "<tr>";    
     echo "<td>". $row['market_name'] . "</td>";    
     echo "</tr>";    
   $n++;    
   }

   echo "</table>";
   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

**sub.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>page</title>
</head>
<body>
    "apple!!!!"
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know what to do to pass and give variables.

Comment: You can POST variables to the next page or you can use SESSION to persist variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display a web page information based on what a user clicks. You can use GET method to pass the variable to another page.

Here is an example:

In your script code, you can append a parameter (that stores the text) to the url.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("table tr td").click(function(){
          displayComment(num);
        });
    });
    function displayComment(num) {
       var txt = $(this).text();
       location.href = `http://220.67.127.177/0513_sub?text=${txt}`;
}
  </script>
```

In your sub.php file, you can check for the GET param and print it if it's available.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
      if (isset($_GET['text'])) {
         echo $_GET['text'];
      }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```